# What is Blink-Jumping?

Tags: dishonored

In a comment on a different question, LessPop_MoreFizz mentioned [Blink-Jumping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89517/which-is-a-better-early-game-choice-for-a-stealth-nonlethal-character-agility-o/89526#comment123307_89526).

**What is Blink-Jumping?

How do you do it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blink-jumping is the term used to describe combining the jump (standard or enhanced with Athletics) with the Blink power.

> You do it in the dream where the Outsider first gives Corvo his powers.  In that dream, there are a few of the platforms that are out of reach of a normal blink; you have to trigger Blink, then jump, and release blink.

This gives you (a) a farther range than you have with Blink alone, and (b) the ability to move higher than you normally are able.  As you increase your agility power, you are also able to jump further, and indeed to double-jump.  Both of these predictably increase your mobility with Blink.  With Blink 2 and Athletics 1, it is quite amazing the freedom that using these together effectively can give Corvo in terms of mobility.

In the linked question, note that the answerer says *"I don't really see how better jumping can help someone playing a stealthy non-killing character..."*.  I infer that this is the reason for the reference to Blink-jumping.

Comment: I was the answerer you quoted. [In the context of the answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89526/4797), I compared *Possession* and *Agility*, noting that *Agility I*'s better jumping won't be very useful (compared to *Possession*) to someone playing a stealthy, non-lethal character. Note that I am not saying blink-jumping is not useful. Also, you can still blink-jump even without *Agility I*.

Comment: I meant that this was the reason for the reference to blink-jumping, not that your opinion was right nor wrong, though from personal use, I can say from personal experience that I definitely have more options for stealthy, non-lethal approaches with Agility I.

Comment: I was just explaining the context of your quote of me, since it could be misunderstood without the context. Also, care to expound on that perspective (by answering or commenting [at the related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89517/4797))? =)

Answer (score 0):

Using blink on areas higher than where you currently are, especially when on edges, such that the blink symbol in the center of the screen is no longer two orbs, but instead arrows pointing up. It can reach higher than a jump (even upgraded jump) and this is especially so with the upgraded blink. The best advantage of blink as a power, is that if you wait for your mana to regen between each blink, its effectively free. That alone has made me less keen on other more heavy powers since I like having a full mana bar.

Comment: This is not what I was referring to. Wraith's answer is correct.